# Getting the attributes of the field in additional EditorTemplate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razorengine, modelmetadata

I want to make additional editor template for the Int32. In it I want to get all attributes(custom/default-data-annotations) and do some work with them:

```
@model Int32

@{
    string propertyName = ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName;
    var attributes = ViewData.ModelMetadata.GetSomeHowAllTheAttributesOfTheProperty;
    SomeWorkWithAttribute(attributes);

}
<input type="text" name="@propertyName" value="@ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayFormatString" class="form-control"/>
```

So the question how to get in the EditorTemplate all attributes of the property?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**: initial answer removed (not enough info in the question):

Since you need to access your custom attribute, I suggest the following:

**A**: if you're just saving some values using your custom attribute, use the `AdditionalMetadataAttribute`:

Model:

```
[Additional("myAdditionalInfoField", "myAdditionalInfoValue")]
public int IntProperty { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@{
    string valueFromAttribute = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Additional["myAdditionalInfoField"].ToString();
}
```

**B**: if you're doing more complex work inside your custom attribute, get the current metadata property for your model and save the computed values inside the `ViewData.ModelMetadata.Additional` dictionary. Please note that this requires that you implement your [custom metadata provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691396/configure-custom-metadataprovider-for-viewmodel).
A detailed implementation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22834146/add-new-property-to-mvc-modelmetadata/22836872#22836872).

Comment: The question is - "How to get all attributes of the property?"

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you completely. "All attributes is a bit generic". MVC "saves" some of the values in the metadata properties. For example, the `Required` attribute is saved in `ModelMetadata.IsRequired` and so forth. Can you be more specific? Another problem is that you're actually targeting a model which is a value type and not a reference type. If it's not a property of a class, you are not able to set attributes. If it's a class property, you need to provide the class instance so that you can retrieve all "explicit" attributes using reflection.

Comment: I Have the Attribute - `MySomeCustomAttribute` I want to be sure that the property have/not have that attribute...

Comment: @Maris, I don't know if that's possible. You could get attribute using reflection but you would need the type of the containing class. Another option would be to use the `AdditionalMetadata` attribute and save your values there. It's much easier and you can access it trough `ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues`.

Comment: I know about `reflection` but hoped that it is arriving somewhere in ViewData... Maybe someone have any idea about it.

Comment: As I said, you can use the `AdditionalMetadata` attribute. It's simple and available in your view.

Comment: @Maris, please take a look at my edits. They might prove useful.

Comment: That is exectly what I was looking for.Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

this is how to access all the attributes in your model property from the DisplayTemplate or EditorTemplate:

```
var attributes = ((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Metadata.DefaultModelMetadata)ViewData.ModelMetadata).Attributes;
```

then you can get the desired custom attribute:

```
var yourAttribute = attributes.PropertyAttributes.OfType<YourAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
```

now you have `yourAttribute` to do what ever you want!